# Unable to generate barcode fonts in SSRS via web application & report builder

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, barcode

Okay, some details, because I know this question has been asked several times, but none of the fixes have resolved my issue.

We have a web application that leverages SSRS as its reporting platform. This application uses a Windows AD user as IIS passthrough to connect the application server to the database server (where SSRS is also installed).

We have an installable barcode font our SSRS reports are using, and it is showing up correctly on the application server, but nowhere else.

The font has been installed and unblocked on the database and application servers for the IIS passthrough user, as well as for the individual users on their workstations, but the font still doesn't show up on workstations in SSRS's report viewer or when exported to PDF. They show up when exported to Word, but with Word being what it is, that results in none of the labels printing correctly.

Also, the passthrough user has been granted full control of the font on each server. We've restarted the reporting server service as well. This is an issue that doesn't present itself when we install the application & SSRS configurations on a single server, but using our production dual-server configuration this is the issue we face.

Comment: I think the barcode font that you're using has a restriction on whether it permits embedding or not. You can check this in the properties->Details tab->Font embeddability property.

Comment: I've confirmed there's no restrictions, and the font displays that it is installable. The type is true type font, as well.

Comment: Is the barcode report item a hidden item and only visible during certain conditions?

Comment: No - and I've already found and referenced all the documentation and other questions that list restrictions and special circumstances like those. The report barcode is a visible item that just shows up as arial when viewed in report view or exported to PDF.

Comment: Is the font installed for `all users` on the production servers? Right click on your font file and select `install font for all user`.

Comment: The production servers are running Windows Server 2016 and don't have the option to install for all users. Besides, the only user that has access to all of the servers is the IIS passthrough user - which has the font installed.